# Change background screen (image) with animation by click button

Tags: java, android

I build an app in Android studio, I finish all the logical part, but still have some stuff that annoying.

**In my app, I have defined the background image in the layout by**

```
android:background="@drawable/firstimg"
```

**and change the background by click on Button with this code:**

```
mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.third);
```

And the background realy changed, but the problem is that how the background changed.

**I need to change the background image with animation.**

I can't use "imageSwitcher" because i define the background picture in the mainLayout, I tried to do it with transition - but its stuck the app and continue very slowely.. I searched and dont find an answer. I will be glad for a little help here.

Comment: It wasn't worked because I cant add an imageView. The image is only in "android: background"

Comment: You can create a activity to test my answer .It woked in my device .You can check it .

Comment: I beleive you that this is working, the problem is that its not suitable to my project, because I dont use "imageView".
In my project, the background is through the XML, and in your project is through imageView. Maybe do u have any suggestion that I use imageView but put on the imageView more widget (button, more images etc)
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clip` in your code .

Try like this .

**clip_drawable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:clipOrientation="horizontal|vertical"
    android:drawable="@drawable/firstimg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

</clip>
```

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/clip_drawable" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/iv"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="setImage"
    android:text="set Image" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="changeImage"
    android:text="change Image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int CHANGE_LEVEL = 99;
private ImageView iv;
private ClipDrawable mClipDrawable;
private boolean isExpand = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
    mClipDrawable = (ClipDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
    mClipDrawable.setLevel(10);
}

public void setImage(View view) {
    if (!isExpand) {
        isExpand = true;
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                if (msg.what == CHANGE_LEVEL) {
                    int level = mClipDrawable.getLevel() + 50;
                    if (level >= 10000) {
                        level = 10000;
                    }
                    mClipDrawable.setLevel(level);
                }
            }
        };
        final CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 10) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                if (mClipDrawable.getLevel() >= 10000) {
                    this.onFinish();
                } else {
                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(99);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                isExpand = false;
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}

public void changeImage(View view) {
    if (iv.getDrawable() != null) {
        iv.setBackground(iv.getDrawable());
    }
    // change image here
    final ClipDrawable imageDrawable = new ClipDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.third), Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START, ClipDrawable.VERTICAL);
    iv.setImageDrawable(imageDrawable);
    imageDrawable.setLevel(10);
    if (!isExpand) {
        isExpand = true;
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                if (msg.what == CHANGE_LEVEL) {
                    int level = imageDrawable.getLevel() + 50;
                    if (level >= 10000) {
                        level = 10000;
                    }
                    imageDrawable.setLevel(level);
                }
            }
        };
        final CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 10) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                if (imageDrawable.getLevel() >= 10000) {
                    this.onFinish();
                } else {
                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(99);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                isExpand = false;
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}
}
```